# Cant open URL's inside Webview

Tags: android, eclipse, webview

I am trying to open a URL when the user clicks on a button inside a WebView on my second Activity.
But it doesn't open inside the WebView component.
its just pop-ups the default browser (in my case Firefox) and loads the URL inside of it.

my code is as follow

On the Main activity;

```
    private void mahButton_1() {
    Button mymessbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myOwnButton);


    mymessbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View WebViewAct) {      
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, WebViewAct.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
}
```

on the other activity;

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);
    WebView mYWeb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    mYWeb.loadUrl("http://google.com/m");
}
```

and in the manifest i did put the following line..

```
<uses-permission 
    android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

i really thould that this would do the job;

```
WebView mYWeb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
mYWeb.loadUrl("http://google.com/m");
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

```
WebView mYWeb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
mYWeb.loadUrl("http://google.com/m");
```

and add this line

```
mYWeb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

Comment: Hello.
Thank you very much, it solved my problem.
But can you please explain why this code made it to work?
What does that line do to be exact?

Comment: this is an version issue. If you run your app above 3.0 you no need to write this line but when you run app in older version this line do a trick because if you not specify the webview client the browser will be treated as default webclient in older version.If you really like the solution you can upvote also for appreciate the answer.

Comment: Thank you again!
Will do!
EDIT: Sorry but i need atleast 15 rep to voteup Sorry :D
I Will (if i dont forget) voteup when i reach 15 rep :)